# check if a process runs on a remote machine for a certain user

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I have to create an executable which checks if a certain process is running for a certain user (a service account) on a remote machine, the input parameters are 3 strings, machine name, user name and process name.

I have the idea to do this using either `System.Diagnostics` or `WMI`, just wanted to double check if anybody has another idea like powershell or even a window functionality which could make the task even easier.

since we want to make sure that process is always running on a dedicated server we will configure a scheduled task to execute a small console application which does this check. Not sure if coding it in C# is the best option or am I ignoring a builtin feature of windows server? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can accomplish this with tasklist cmd: `tasklist /S \\<server> /V > tasklist.txt`.  this will give you a file you can grep through.

Comment: thanks, this is good but I would still need to parse the resulting file and I would need .NET code for that.

Comment: try `tasklist /S \\[machine name] /V /FI "USERNAME eq [user name]" /FI "IMAGENAME eq [process name]"`

Comment: I did a little more playing with some of the other options.  There is some good stuff in there!  For a cleaner result, take off the `/V` and put on a `/NH` (No Header).  Also, adding `/SVC` helped to clean some of the other columns (but I'm not sure exactly what it specifies).

Answer (score 1):

namespace not referenced
using System.Management;

I have ended up by implementing following solution in C#

this retrieves the username without domain name of the user running `processName` on `machineName`

```
public static string GetProcessOwner()
{
    try
    {
        var resultUserName = string.Empty;

        ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();

        string path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", machineName);

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, opt);

        scope.Connect();

        var query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = '{0}'", processName));
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        var processList = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
        {
            string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
            int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));

            if (returnVal == 0)
            {
                // return DOMAIN\user 
                //return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
                resultUserName = argList[0];
            }
        }

        return resultUserName; 
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetOwner can return empty array for remote comp, so it may not work